# Obtener nombre de objeto php y mostrarlo en div Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, html5, css3

El problema es que no se si a parte del **id** del **expediente** puedo pasar como segundo argumento el **nombre**.
Tengo dos vistas: la vista **historia.blade.php** y **crear.blade.php**
Tengo un este **enlace** en **historia.blade.php** y al hacer click te lleva a la otra vista.

`<a href="{{ route('expediente-nuevo', $usuario->id) }}" class="btn btn-success">Crear Expediente</a>`

Ese enlace me lleva a la `function create` de **ExpedienteController**

```
Route::get('/expedientes/nuevo-expediente', [App\Http\Controllers\ExpedienteController::class, 'create'])->name('expediente-nuevo');
```

En **ExpedienteController** he puesto esto:

```
    public function create($id)
    {
        
        return view('expediente.crear');
    }
```

Y en la vista **crear.blade.php** esta el div para poner el nombre.

Comment: Si ya envías el id, ¿para qué necesitas el nombre?

Comment: Necesito poner los dos datos

Comment: La documentación en la sección de rutas expone como pasar variables, chécalo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías manejarlo de la siguiente forma:

Colocando tu enlace como: `<a href="/expedientes/nuevo-expediente/{$usuario->id}/{$usuario->nombre}" class="btn btn-success">Crear Expediente</a>`

Modificando tu ruta por: `Route::get('/expedientes/nuevo-expediente/{id}/{nombre}', [App\Http\Controllers\ExpedienteController::class, 'create']);`

Tu expediente controller debería ser:

```
public function create($id,$nombre)
    {
        $data = array('id'=>$id, 'nombre'=>$nombre);
        return view('expediente.crear')->with($data);
    }
```

Y en tu crear.blade.php puedes hacer uso de ambos a través de: `{{$id}} {{$nombre}}`